# GLIBCXX_3.4.26 Not found

Tags: c++, g++, libstdc++

I am trying to build open embedded project. But it shows some error like

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found
```

How can i install GLIBCXX_3.4.26 in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 10):

I believe the object you are trying to use was compiled with a fairly recent version of GCC 9 with [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83328) fixed.  This GCC version has not yet been released.

You need to recompile it with the Ubuntu system compiler, or ask the Ubuntu compiler people to backport this fix into the Ubuntu 16.04 system compiler (which seems fairly unlikely to happen at this point).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04 worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by 2 steps:

1 Install a Anaconda3

2 Copy the file libstdc++.so.6.0.26 to path '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu', then create a soft link.

I worte the detail commands [here](https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/1526#issuecomment-1278627574).